# The init script works fine in databricks notebook but fails when attached to cluster

Tags: python, bash, cluster-computing, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to attach the init script (which has all library dependencies) with an interactive cluster in databricks. The init script look like the below attachment and works fine in databricks notebook.
[image]

I want this shell script to run at cluster start, but when I configure it as a init script for the cluster it returns an error. Here's how I have attached the init script to my cluster,
[image]

The error look like this,
[image]

I found a [url](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/37303/script-works-on-notebook-but-fails-on-init-script.html) discussing the same problem but solution provided here (changing extension of the file from .sh to .bash) doesn't work for me. Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please do remove extra (`"`) to successfully install init script.

**As per my repro:** I have used the same code as above.

[image]

**Result:**  Cluster terminated Reason: Init Script Failure

[image]

After removing extra quote (`"`).

[image]

**Result:** Init_Scripts successfully installed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't been able to figure out even after staring at this bash script for hours that what exactly is wrong with this.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but mine was that I used `sudo apt install something`, and after sometime I realized that I needed to add the `-y` flag, because the command need a user input. So try to avoid user input commands or add flags like:

```sh
sudo apt install -y package
```