# Azure Cluster, Cluster terminated.Reason:Network configuration failure

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm unable to start a Azure cluster today:

[image]

Sometimes I get this error, sometimes this passes but I get the following:

[image]

Any idea as to what this is due to?

Comment: Please share Init script

Comment: I'm not able to access it via dbfs, nor running a command since the cluster's not working

Comment: it looks like networking issues in your workspace. Maybe firewalls where added or something like this?

Comment: No firewalls were added by us workers. This happened at night.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in error message,

> This may happen because your VMs do not have outbound connectivity to
> DBFS storage. Also consider upgrading your cluster to a later spark
> version.

Upgrade your cluster to a later spark version. This may resolve your issue.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63153393/the-init-script-works-fine-in-databricks-notebook-but-fails-when-attached-to-clu) SO question

Comment: Spark version is fine, we run another cluster with the same version and it works properly.